# Apache Atlas failing with CosmosDB Cassandra API

Tags: java, azure, janusgraph, apache-atlas, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

I am trying to set up Apache Atlas with CosmosDB Cassandra API with `Strong` as the default consistency level. During startup after ~10 seconds I get this null pointer exception:-

```
2023-12-19 08:23:29,335 DEBUG - [main:] ~ ==> AtlasTypeRegistry.addTypesWithNoRefResolve(length=0) (AtlasTypeRegistry$AtlasTransientTypeRegistry:789)
2023-12-19 08:23:29,335 DEBUG - [main:] ~ <== AtlasTypeRegistry.addTypesWithNoRefResolve(length=0) (AtlasTypeRegistry$AtlasTransientTypeRegistry:800)
2023-12-19 08:23:29,336 DEBUG - [main:] ~ <== lockTypeRegistryForUpdate() (AtlasTypeRegistry$TypeRegistryUpdateSynchronizer:981)
2023-12-19 08:23:29,338 DEBUG - [main:] ~ ==> AtlasEnumDefStoreV2.getAll() (AtlasEnumDefStoreV2:99)
2023-12-19 08:23:29,345 DEBUG - [main:] ~ Executing: OrCondition [andExprs=AndExpr [predicates=[HasTerm [propertyName=__type, op=EQUAL, value=typeSystem], HasTerm [propertyName=__type.category, op=EQUAL, value=ENUM]]]] (TinkerpopGraphQuery:129)
2023-12-19 08:23:29,443 ERROR  - [main:] ~ !!! error while getting AtlasEnumDef (AtlasEnumDefStoreV2:111)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.verifyAttribute(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:636)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.QueryUtil.addConstraint(QueryUtil.java:329)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.QueryUtil.constraints2QNF(QueryUtil.java:233)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.graph.GraphCentricQueryBuilder.constructQueryWithoutProfile(GraphCentricQueryBuilder.java:271)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.graph.GraphCentricQueryBuilder.constructQuery(GraphCentricQueryBuilder.java:255)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.graph.GraphCentricQueryBuilder.vertices(GraphCentricQueryBuilder.java:225)
        at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.query.NativeJanusGraphQuery.vertices(NativeJanusGraphQuery.java:65)
        at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.tinkerpop.query.TinkerpopGraphQuery.vertices(TinkerpopGraphQuery.java:137)
        at org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.v2.AtlasTypeDefGraphStoreV2.findTypeVerticesByCategory(AtlasTypeDefGraphStoreV2.java:164)
        at org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.v2.AtlasEnumDefStoreV2.getAll(AtlasEnumDefStoreV2.java:102)
        at org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.AtlasTypeDefGraphStore.init(AtlasTypeDefGraphStore.java:102)
        at org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.v2.AtlasTypeDefGraphStoreV2.init(AtlasTypeDefGraphStoreV2.java:118)
```

In cosmosdb cassandra explorer I can see some of tables created:-

[image]

What is the reason for this exception and how should I resolve it ? It works fine when I try to run it with a simple Cassandra instance.